# Matplotlib prompts python launched to open in Flask Application

Tags: python, matplotlib, flask

I'm writing a Flask application, and I use `matplotlib` to create a bar graph and save the image to display it on the browser (which works). However, when I open the page with the image, the python launcher tries to open, and then quits by itself, giving me a working saying that the app quit unexpectedly. But my problem is not that it doesn't open, it is that I don't want the python launcher to open in the first place since I only use `matplotlib` to create the plot image.
Reminder: In my Flask page, the image appears correctly, and while I'm still using the browser python launcher prompts and quits. The problem is that I want to prevent it from launching in the first place.

I have two functions, one which returns the `matplotlib` figure, and the other that creates an image and saves it onto the route `/plot.png`.

Here is the first one that returns a figure (I've excluded the part where I calculate the values `bar_x` and `bar_y` since I know that this first function generates the correct graph:

```
def bar_graph(doesn_matter):
    fig = plt.gcf()
    plt.title("Bar (Spreading of transactions)")
    plt.bar(bar_x, bar_y)
    plt.show()
    return fig
```

And here is the function that generates the image from the `matplotlib` figure:
(`purchases` is a global variable that is always changing, and the plot that is shown is based on this variable. The other problem is that the charts are always overlapping when I change the graph)

```
@app.route('/plot.png')
@login_required
def plot_png():
    global purchases
    fig = bar_graph(purchases)
    return nocache(fig_response(fig))

def fig_response(fig):
    """Turn a matplotlib Figure into Flask response"""
    img_bytes = io.BytesIO()
    fig.savefig(img_bytes)
    img_bytes.seek(0)
    return send_file(img_bytes, mimetype='image/png')

def nocache(response):
    """Add Cache-Control headers to disable caching a response"""
    response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0'
    return response
```

And finally, if it's relevant, this is how I call the image in my Flask HTML template:

```
<img src="/plot.png" alt="Plot Results">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might have changed recently, but the standard method for making matplotlib work in with Flask (or other headless applications) has long been to include

```
matplotlib.use('agg')
```

immediately after

```
import matplotlib
```

Comment: Hello! This worked, but when I reload the page and create a different graph, the previous bar also appears.

Comment: Is there any way to 'clear' the graph every time?

Comment: You'll need to defeat caching. For one way to do that, see https://github.com/davewsmith/play/blob/master/matplotlib-flask/app.py#L65

Comment: But there is no function called `nocache` or even `fig_responde` in either python or Matplotlib.

Comment: They're the two functions immediately below

Comment: Thanks! But I used `no cache` and `fig_response` and the chart still overlaps with previous reloads of the page

Comment: Show your revised code. Are you sure `purchases` is changing between requests?

Comment: `purchases` is a global variable, that is always changing. To give you a better context, these represent stock trades, and before you enter the page that displays the chart, there is a form that allows the user to choose which stock the chart will be based on. So if I enter the page, then go back, and enter again with a different stock, the chart shows both of them overlapping and it is confusing for the user. I'm editing the question with the revised code.

Comment: I got it to work! Instead of using `plt.gcf()` I used `plt.figure`. Thank you very much for the effort! It truly helped!